# EOG (Image Viewer) fails to open gif files with incorrect png extension - how can I solve this?

Tags: command-line, file-format, eog

I have a bunch of files that have `.png` extension.  However, some of them are actually gif files. I can open any of the files with gimp or view them in firefox, but when I try to open them with the Eye of Gnome viewer, it gives an error

> Could not load image: Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file

Is there:

1. Another image viewer that can open files with incorrect extensions that I could use as default?   It would need to have the ability to zoom in and out on images, and scroll through all the images in a folder via arrow keys.
2. An automated way to rename the files that are actually gif files to the correct extensions?

Choice 2 is preferred, but I don't know how to tell what type they are.  I would be able to put together a Bash script to do the renaming if there is a command that could tell me the file type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use (from command line or within a script... if you need the script just ask ;) ) the command `file thisimage.png`, it will tell you what image format you actually have.... Then you can rename accordingly...

This is a sample of what I get with a file with incorrect file extension .png which is really a jpg file:

```
user@computer:$ file logo.png
logo.png: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01
```

Edit: Oh, ok, I was lazy before... Here's an script that will rename actual gif files that are named with .png extension to their correct extension .gif:

```
#!/bin/bash
for NAME in $(ls *.png); do

if [ "$(file $NAME|grep GIF)" ]; then

echo "Renaming ${NAME} to ${NAME%.*}.gif"
mv ${NAME} ${NAME%.*}.gif

fi

done
```

Comment: I know that this can probably be accomplished quite more easily with a single line using ´find´ with ´exec´ and such, but I'm not a 'scripter' at all, so anyone should feel free to edit my answer and add a shorter command, if you wish.

Comment: This answer was of great help when debugging a javascript driven image download script. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the file extension, and Eye of Gnome will be able to view your images. For example, the image below is a file with no extension:

   [image: image appears fine]

   This, however may be not useful for you if you wish the files to have the correct extension.
2. To correct the extensions instead, you may be interested in [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/), which will allow you to perform batch process for renaming and several other tasks.

   [image: Phatch dialog]

   [image: Rename action in Phatch]

Additionally you may be interested in the [Nautilus Scripts Pack](http://linux-apps.com/content/show.php/Ultimate+Edition+Nautilus+Scripts+Pack?content=104451) which makes the image conversion as easy as a single click.