# After update 15.04 to 15.10 just black screen on boot

Tags: boot, updates, freeze, 15.10

On my Laptop (Acer 3820) I updated from 15.04 to 15.10
After the restart I just get only a black screen. At first you can see the ubuntu loading Logo, but after that just nothing. So I tried to use <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but that is not working, just nothing.

I figured out that <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> only works at beginning of the loading screen, if I press that right at the start I can see some cryptic text (see picture):

[image: His Picture]

This is the last thing you can see, after that the screen just gets black again and nothing. Cannot continue, <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is not working anymore.

Well... any ideas? Does the picture help?

I could create an USB with the Ubuntu 15.10 installation on it and start a "reinstall", that way I can keep at least my home folder right? But any other settings will be lost - maybe there is another solution for that. Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your laptop has **switchable graphics** as described here http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-3820TG-Timeline-X-Notebook.30294.0.html

This is comparable to nvidia optimus which i have to same problem with [Bumblebee Intel+Nvidia on 15.10 blackscreen issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689924/bumblebee-intelnvidia-on-15-10-blackscreen-issue)

Someone told me it is a bug with i915 + 4.2 kernel see comments in http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.fr/2015/10/how-to-install-bumblebee-and-latest.html

But yet i don't have a clue. But nvidia driver is working fine so looking at your thread this looks the is really problem with the i915 driver, what is strange is that i tried to use different kerneles and still got the same issue see https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?69190-Bumblebee-Nvidia355&p=381043

I also posted a thread here for interested people http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2300628

Comment: I just dont know how to see the error log in ubuntu, somehow there is an information why the whole thing crashed? And yes it's a switchable graphics - BUT because I had some trouble with the drivers I deactivated the intel/amd switch long time ago. So there is always the same GPU (AMD) is running all the time.

Comment: well you can use ```journalctl -xn``` to see errors, if that  helps
And to access a terminal try holding <kbd>maj</kbd> on boot and select advanced boot option in grub and the **rescue** option for the last kernel you have which may be 4.2

Comment: Also this thread could give you some more info, but seriously i don't understand every thing in it http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743535

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it there is an ati related bug fix in it