# Bumblebee fail safe x after reboot [GTX 755M][Ubuntu 15.10]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

When I installed bumblebee and the nvidia-340 drivers Ubuntu booted into a normal session. On the next reboot, after running glmark2 with optirun in the previous session, the normal x session would not start up and I instead got a screen with the message "The system is running in low-graphics mode". If I lock the xorg.config that is generated to a blank file with

```
$ chattr +i /etc/X11/xorg.config
```

I get to the login screen but as soon as I log in something crashes and I am returned to the login screen once again.

The Xorg.0.log befor low graphics mode

```
[    21.150] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    21.397] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    21.397] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    21.397] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    21.397] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    21.398] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    21.398] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    21.398] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    21.398] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    21.522] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    21.522]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.522] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    21.522]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.522] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    21.522]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.534] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    21.534]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.534] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    21.534]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    21.534] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    21.534] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    21.534] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    21.549] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a1d1724d40
[    21.549] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    21.549]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    21.549]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[    21.549]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.0
[    21.549]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    21.549] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    21.551] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:3801 rev 6, Mem @ 0xc2000000/4194304, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[    21.560] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    21.560] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    21.560] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    21.711] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    22.171] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.171]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    22.171]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    22.171] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    22.171] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    22.171] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 1
[    22.171] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    22.171] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    22.171] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    22.171] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    22.171] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    22.171] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    22.311] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.312]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
[    22.312]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.312]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.312] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.312] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    22.363] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.363]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    22.363]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.363]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.363] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.363] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    22.376] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.376]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.4
[    22.376]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.376]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.376] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    22.376] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    22.423] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.423]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.4
[    22.423]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    22.423]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.423] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    22.423] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    22.423] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    22.423] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    22.423] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    22.423] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    22.423] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    22.423] (++) using VT number 7

[    22.442] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20150522
[    22.442] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20150808-0ubuntu4 (Robert Ancell <robert.ancell@canonical.com>)
[    22.442] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    22.466] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    22.467] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    22.467] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    22.467] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.467] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    22.494] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    22.494]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    22.494]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    22.494] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    22.505] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
[    22.505] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    22.505] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    22.505] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    22.505] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    22.505] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    22.505] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[    22.516] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Output VGA1 has no monitor section
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VGA1
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    22.516] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    22.516] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    22.516] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1600x900 on pipe 0
[    22.516] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    22.516] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    22.516] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    22.516] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    22.516] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    22.516] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    22.516] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    22.516] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    22.516] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    22.516] (II) Unloading modesetting
[    22.516] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    22.516] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    22.516] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    22.516] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    22.516] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    22.516] (II) Unloading vesa
[    22.516] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    22.581] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Haswell (gen7.5, gt2) backend
[    22.582] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    22.582] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    22.593] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    22.593] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    22.594] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    22.594] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    22.594] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    22.594] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    22.594] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    22.594] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    22.594] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    22.594] (--) RandR disabled
[    22.598] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[    22.938] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    22.938] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    22.941] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1600x900@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    22.941] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 423 x 238
[    23.043] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    23.075] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    23.075] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.075] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    23.075] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    23.114] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.114]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.9.2
[    23.114]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    23.114]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    23.114] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    23.114] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.114] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    23.115] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    23.115] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    23.115] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.115] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[    23.115] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.115] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[    23.115] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.115] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    23.115] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    23.115] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[    23.115] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    23.115] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    23.115] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.115] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input8/event6"
[    23.115] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.115] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.116] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    23.116] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.116] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    23.116] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    23.116] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    23.116] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    23.116] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    23.116] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.116] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    23.116] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.116] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    23.116] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.116] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Sleep Button'
[    23.116] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    23.116] (**) evdev: Sleep Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    23.116] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x3
[    23.116] (--) evdev: Sleep Button: Found keys
[    23.116] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.116] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:01/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[    23.116] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.116] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.117] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[    23.117] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.117] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Video Bus'
[    23.117] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    23.117] (**) evdev: Video Bus: Device: "/dev/input/event5"
[    23.117] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Vendor 0 Product 0x6
[    23.117] (--) evdev: Video Bus: Found keys
[    23.117] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.117] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:4c/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event5"
[    23.117] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    23.117] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.117] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.117] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.117] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event2)
[    23.117] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.117] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.117] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
[    23.117] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.117] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.117] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event10)
[    23.117] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.117] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.118] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event11)
[    23.118] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.118] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.118] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lenovo EasyCamera (/dev/input/event14)
[    23.118] (**) Lenovo EasyCamera: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.118] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Lenovo EasyCamera'
[    23.118] (**) Lenovo EasyCamera: always reports core events
[    23.118] (**) evdev: Lenovo EasyCamera: Device: "/dev/input/event14"
[    23.118] (--) evdev: Lenovo EasyCamera: Vendor 0x174f Product 0x1474
[    23.118] (--) evdev: Lenovo EasyCamera: Found keys
[    23.118] (II) evdev: Lenovo EasyCamera: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.118] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input15/event14"
[    23.118] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Lenovo EasyCamera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    23.118] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.118] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.118] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.118] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event12)
[    23.118] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.118] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.118] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event13)
[    23.118] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    23.118] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    23.119] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Ideapad extra buttons (/dev/input/event8)
[    23.119] (**) Ideapad extra buttons: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.119] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Ideapad extra buttons'
[    23.119] (**) Ideapad extra buttons: always reports core events
[    23.119] (**) evdev: Ideapad extra buttons: Device: "/dev/input/event8"
[    23.119] (--) evdev: Ideapad extra buttons: Vendor 0 Product 0
[    23.119] (--) evdev: Ideapad extra buttons: Found keys
[    23.119] (II) evdev: Ideapad extra buttons: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.119] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input9/event8"
[    23.119] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Ideapad extra buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.119] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    23.119] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    23.119] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    23.119] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    23.119] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    23.119] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[    23.119] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[    23.119] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    23.119] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[    23.119] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    23.119] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    23.119] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/event7)
[    23.119] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev touchpad catchall"
[    23.119] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[    23.119] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[    23.119] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[    23.119] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[    23.126] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    23.126]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.8.2
[    23.126]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    23.126]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[    23.126] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad'
[    23.127] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[    23.127] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    23.140] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: found clickpad property
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 2800 (res 33)
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 1820 (res 33)
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 255
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 0 - 15
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0xe
[    23.140] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[    23.140] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    23.140] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[    23.152] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event7"
[    23.152] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 14)
[    23.152] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[    23.152] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[    23.152] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.060
[    23.152] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    23.152] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[    23.152] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    23.152] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    23.152] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[    23.152] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    23.152] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[    24.516] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 8254
[    24.516] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    24.516] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0  110.00  1600 1664 1706 2010  900 903 906 912 -hsync -vsync (54.7 kHz eP)
[    24.516] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1600x900"x0.0   73.33  1600 1664 1706 2010  900 903 906 912 -hsync -vsync (36.5 kHz e)
[    44.439] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    46.119] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    46.126] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    55.951] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-7C75F152E85183199599C3E0B919739C0EE668AA.xkm
```

Xorg.0.log after low-graphics mode

```
[    50.337] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    50.337] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    50.337] Build Operating System: Linux 3.19.0-30-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    50.337] Current Operating System: Linux Io 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    50.337] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/sdb5
[    50.337] Build Date: 30 September 2015  09:08:47AM
[    50.337] xorg-server 2:1.17.2-1ubuntu9 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    50.337] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    50.337]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    50.337] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    50.337] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Oct 27 20:08:20 2015
[    50.337] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    50.337] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    50.337] Data incomplete in file /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    Undefined Screen "nvidia" referenced by ServerLayout "layout".
[    50.337] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[    50.337] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[    50.337] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    50.337] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    50.337] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    50.337] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    50.337] (EE) 
[    50.337] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

My bumblebee.config

```
# Configuration file for Bumblebee. Values should **not** be put between quotes

## Server options. Any change made in this section will need a server restart
# to take effect.
[bumblebeed]
# The secondary Xorg server DISPLAY number
VirtualDisplay=:8
# Should the unused Xorg server be kept running? Set this to true if waiting
# for X to be ready is too long and don't need power management at all.
KeepUnusedXServer=false
# The name of the Bumbleblee server group name (GID name)
ServerGroup=bumblebee
# Card power state at exit. Set to false if the card shoud be ON when Bumblebee
# server exits.
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
# The default behavior of '-f' option on optirun. If set to "true", '-f' will
# be ignored.
NoEcoModeOverride=false
# The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),
# auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau
# (See also the driver-specific sections below)
Driver=nvidia
# Directory with a dummy config file to pass as a -configdir to secondary X
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

## Client options. Will take effect on the next optirun executed.
[optirun]
# Acceleration/ rendering bridge, possible values are auto, virtualgl and
# primus.
Bridge=auto
# The method used for VirtualGL to transport frames between X servers.
# Possible values are proxy, jpeg, rgb, xv and yuv.
VGLTransport=proxy
# List of paths which are searched for the primus libGL.so.1 when using
# the primus bridge
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
# Should the program run under optirun even if Bumblebee server or nvidia card
# is not available?
AllowFallbackToIGC=false


# Driver-specific settings are grouped under [driver-NAME]. The sections are
# parsed if the Driver setting in [bumblebeed] is set to NAME (or if auto-
# detection resolves to NAME).
# PMMethod: method to use for saving power by disabling the nvidia card, valid
# values are: auto - automatically detect which PM method to use
#         bbswitch - new in BB 3, recommended if available
#       switcheroo - vga_switcheroo method, use at your own risk
#             none - disable PM completely
# https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Comparison-of-PM-methods

## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-340
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340:/usr/lib32/nvidia-340
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-340/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

## Section with nouveau driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nouveau
[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

the xorg.config file that was generated on the boot after running optirun

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection
```

Comment: I ended up solving my problem by using this solution http://askubuntu.com/q/689924/238833