# Nvidia-361 GPU installation continual rebooting

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.10, gpu, gpu-driver

I've got Ubuntu 15.10 installed on a new Asus Z170-AR motherboard.  I've also got a `Nvidia GTX 980 ti` I'm trying to get working with it.

I `purge`ed all Nvidia packages, and followed the instructions in this post: [Bumblebee Intel+Nvidia on 15.10 blackscreen issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689924/bumblebee-intelnvidia-on-15-10-blackscreen-issue), except I installed `nvidia-361` instead, which seems to be the latest.

It boots, but when it boots the desktop appears, in the full 3820 resolution of the monitor, but then it reboots again, and just does this over and over.

Any thoughts on the approach I should use to get this new GPU installed correctly?

I'm concerned that it's not possible with 15.10, but I doubt that's true.  Also, I don't think this is an issue, but it could be: Nvidia's website specifies GCC 4.9, and Ubuntu 15.1 comes with >5.  I don't think that's the issue because this is a boot thing and not a compilation thing, but who knows.

I am going to try an earlier `nvidia-3**` package.  I would try Ubuntu 14 but could not get that installed with this motherboard.

I did have `nouveau.modeset=0` set to zero at the end of the linux line in the grub menu but upon viewing that again it is not there.

EDIT/ADD: this is single boot.  And I see that the grub menu only works for one boot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hope it's ok to answer my own question.

I followed the instructions in the linked to answer in my question, which mostly consisted of purging nvidia packages and adding a package repository, and then added `nomodeset` to the linux line in the [grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) (Once to the grub menu hit `e` to edit.  I got my grub menu using 15.1 by hitting `esc` once at the motherboard bios display and once more about two seconds after that disappeared).

1. `apt-get purge` as described in link found in above question
2. add `nomodeset` to linux line in grub menu (see detail above)
3. install `nvidia-358`
4. reboot