# Ubuntu 15.10 crashed on MSI GE 60 2PC (nouveau driver bug, 'GPU stuck')

Tags: 15.10

I did fresh installation of ubuntu 15.10 but there's a problem when I logged in. This also happended when I do upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10.

The system just stopped working, no responses from the system. It just hang there and I can't move the mouse or use keyboard. I think the system is crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nouveau is actually crashing, it is unstable as hell. On msi GT70 I just managed to install **nvidia-prime** and **bumblebee**. I strongly recommend this as you have **Optimus** on your laptop.

To do so, try to boot in rescue mode on ethernet and follow these :

[Bumblebee Intel+Nvidia on 15.10 blackscreen issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689924/bumblebee-intelnvidia-on-15-10-blackscreen-issue)

```
I have manage to make this work https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?69190-Bumblebee-Nvidia355&p=381043

1. install nvidia-355 and nvidia-prime

2. select intel driver in nvidia panel and logout

3. install bumblebee only (not bumblebee-nvidia)

4. edit as needed /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
line22 KernelDriver=nvidia
replace nvidia-current by nvidia-355

5. /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
uncomment BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
as described here https://askubuntu.com/questions/29044...vices-detected,

6. you can now boot under intel card and use optirun and primusrun. It is working for me so far, test with primusrun glxinfo
```

Another option is just tu install nvidia-prime and nvidia-352, or if you want the last nvidia driver you can use `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` to get nvidia-355 from this ppa.

Comment: Now I can't enter the setup from usb, keep crashing.

Comment: Hold <kbd>maj</kbd> when booting and select adanced options in grub, then select rescue mode. This way you will be able to have a root shell and have a connection so you could use apt-get

Comment: thank you, I managed to boot into the system and change the additional driver from x.org to nvidia-352. It seems to work fine :D